# r : getting a value from a raw

Tags: r, dataset, subset

I have this data set and i'd like to get  a sub set with ony the algerian values in it
https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus/country/algeria?fbclid=IwAR1HqdWrBlQPOhuNj0yyvn9ObAIWHTs8ySHnZyLsMFv1WAA-1cRIwCj75y8

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

### 1. Download the data

```
url <- "https://covid.ourworldindata.org"
path <- "data"
fname <- "owid-covid-data.csv"

fl <- file.path(url, path, fname)
tmp <- tempfile()
download.file(fl, tmp)
#trying URL 'https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv'
#downloaded 32.8 MB
```

### 2. Check success

```
file.exists(tmp)
#[1] TRUE
```

### 3. Read and subset

```
df1 <- read.csv(tmp) |> subset(location == "Algeria")
dim(df1)
#[1] 605  65
```

### 3b. Previous versions of R

The pipe operator was introduced in R4.1.0. To run with previous versions of R use

```
df1 <- read.csv(tmp)
df1 <- subset(df1, location == "Algeria")
dim(df1)
# [1] 605  65
```

---

If you want to keep the file, move it to a permanent directory.

Comment: Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:23: unexpected '>'
1: df1 <- read.csv(tmp) |>

Comment: @djouahdhia The pipe operator was introduced in R 4.1.0, what is you version of R? Time to update? Anyway I will post a version without the pipe.